# How to create Django objects that have foreign key field referenced on field which haven't contain data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I faced with problem while creating django objects. I have two models

```
class League(models.Model):
   league_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  
   league_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   league_logo = models.URLField(null = True)     
   league_flag = models.URLField(null = True)     
   standings = models.IntegerField(null=True)     
   is_current = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class Fixture(models.Model):                      
    fixture = models.IntegerField (primary_key=True)                                                    
    league_id = models.ForeignKey('League',null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)                      
    event_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    event_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

When i am trying to create object from my fixture model and  in this time i have not any data in league table. I get an error that

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
     File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/forecast/odds.py", line 53, in <module>
     fixt = Fixture.objects.create_or_update(fixture_id = fixture_id,league_id_id = league_id,event_date = event_date,)
    AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'create_or_update'
    >>> import odds
    /data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/forecast
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 240, in _commit
     self._commit()
     File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 240, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise     dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
   File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 240, in _commit
   return self.connection.commit()
   django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "dataflow_fixture" violates foreign key constraint "dataflow_fixture_league_id_id_674984dc_fk_dataflow_"
   DETAIL:  Key (league_id_id)=(780) is not present in table "dataflow_league".
```

Like i understand this error occur because while i am creating a fixture object and process of creating reach league_id field and its reference to league_id field in League table which doesnt contain any data in this moment. I was thinking that for solve this problem i can change order of creating objects and create league objects first and than create fixture objects. But my league model also have foreign key field which reference on objects which doesnt exist. Is django have any method to go around this kind of troubles ???

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
league_id = models.ForeignKey('League',null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

in your `Fixture` model. Perhaps changing it to the following will allow you to create `Fixture` without specifying the `league_id` at the beginning, and you can add it later, after filling out the `League` table.

```
league_id = models.ForeignKey('League',null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```